# PHP best way to echo variables

Tags: php, variables, echo

I was watching a PHP tutorial and noticed that the teacher was adding varibles to his echo statements in a different way to me. This got me thinking, which way should I be using? Is one more correct than the other?

Here's what the teacher was doing

```
echo "Example " . $example;
```

Here's what I do

```
echo "Example $example";
```

My method works, but I don't want to get into any bad habits. Could someone please tell me which way I should be using (preferably with some evidence)?

Comment: they are both valid, but the first example is easier to read in most text editors and hence make changes to later.

Comment: You could also wrap your variable in `{}` - `echo "Example {$example}";`

Comment: _`echo "Example ", $example;`_ also works. note `comma` as the separator rather than a `fullstop` which is the concatenation operator. It is useful when dealing with strings which use the different types of qoute characters in a string.

Comment: I think that the second version is more readable and less error prone, especially if you have more than one variable to concatenate.

Comment: That's a good point. I think its tough to say if one is hands down better than the other.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the PHP.NET documentation, his way is proper.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
echo "Example " . $example;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I suppose Ill start using his method

Comment: "his way is proper" --- and the OP's method is not?